# Where is the boot-time diskchk log in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, logging, check-disk

When Windows 7 does a disk check on boot time, where is the log afterwards? In the old times (XP) there was a log in the root directory, and even a special directory where the lost clusters were placed. Where is all this under win7?

Comment: Look in the Event Viewer. It may be in the Application or System log. I forget which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start --> Run --> eventvwr --> Windows Logs --> Application --> Filter source: "Wininit".

Comment: It's there, but it doesn't seem to save the whole log, just like the beginning and then a "...". Pathetic... Time to switch to linux.. :p